# Edit drop down but not showing selected value from mysql data base in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am new to php, i created drop down which calling data from mysql data base, user selects option and its save to data base.

Problem Arises in edit form in which its do not showing selected value.

Drop Down code is below:

```
$query = 'SELECT name FROM owner';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error in query: $query. ' . mysql_error());

//create selection list
echo "<select name='owner'>\name";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $heading = $row[0];
    echo "<option value='$heading'>$heading\n";
}
echo "</select>"
```

Please advise solution for the edit form.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Look, this question has nothing to do with PHP. You have to learn HTML first. Or at least make your HTML work before starting with PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT name FROM owner';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error in query: $query. ' . mysql_error());

//create selection list
echo "<select name='owner'>\name";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $heading = $row[0];
?>
    <option <?php if($heading=="SOMETHING") { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="SOMETHING">SOMETHING</option>
<option <?php if($heading=="SOMETHING2") { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="SOMETHING2">SOMETHING2</option>
<option <?php if($heading=="SOMETHING3") { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="SOMETHING3">SOMETHING3</option>
<?php
}
echo "</select>"
```

Comment: what if there would be 4 records? what about using a loop to display options?

Comment: Dear Mohit, Thx for the help, but i have one questions, there is no any other value in list other then seleted value

Comment: @Col what if select box is static and he save only selected value in database almost 90% people use static select box and copy it in edit pages and first understand what he wants then say he got his answer

Comment: @Muhmmad then your code is correct you just need to close option </option>

Comment: and no need of \n in select box

Answer (score 3):

you must close `<option>` tag:
`echo "<option value='$heading'>$heading</option>";`

Answer (score -2):

I'd do it this way.

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($numrows != 0){
    echo "<select name='owner'>\name";
    while ($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
       echo "<option value='".$x['heading']."'>".$x['heading']."</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
}
```

$x['heading'] is using the value of the row 'heading' in the database

It's much more efficient and simply looks more sophisticated.

Comment: you have some copy-paste errors (like undeclared `$heading` variable)

Comment: Muhmmad Yasir: Change 'heading' in $x['heading'] to what you called the row in your database that is storing the heading.